# Fortran weird assignment, is 4294967295 == .true.?

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, gdb, variable-assignment

I have a fortran subroutine which looks like this.

```
subroutine load_ed_ecosystem_params()

   use pft_coms    , only : include_these_pft   & ! intent(in)
                          , is_tropical         & ! intent(out)
                          , is_liana              ! intent(out)
   implicit none
   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------! 
   !    This flag should be used to define whether the plant is tropical/subtropical or    !
   ! not.                                                                                  !
   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------! 
   is_tropical(1:4)   = .true.
   is_tropical(5:11)  = .false.
   is_tropical(12:13) = .false.
   is_tropical(14:15) = .true.
   is_tropical(16)    = .true.
   is_tropical(17)    = .true.
   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!

   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
   !    This flag should be used to define whether the plant is a liana or not             !
   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
   is_liana(1:16)  = .false.
   is_liana(17)    = .true.
   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
```

The arrays `is_tropical` and `is_liana` are defined in the `pft_coms.f90` file.
The arrays were taking weird values so I run the executable in gdb. I broke the file just before the assignment and right after it. Before the assignment I get

```
Breakpoint 1, load_ed_ecosystem_params () at ed_params.f90:87
87     is_tropical(1:4)   = .true.

(gdb) print is_tropical
$2 = (.FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE.)

(gdb) print is_liana   
$3 = (.FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE.)
```

like they should since they are initialized this way. After running the few next lines I get

```
(gdb) n
88     is_tropical(5:11)  = .false.
(gdb) n
89     is_tropical(12:13) = .false.
(gdb) n
90     is_tropical(14:15) = .true.
(gdb) n
91     is_tropical(16)    = .true.
(gdb) n
96     is_tropical(17)    = .true.
(gdb) n
102    is_liana(1:16)  = .false.
(gdb) n
103    is_liana(17)    = .true.
(gdb) print is_tropical
$4 = (4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295, 4294967295)
(gdb) print is_liana
$6 = (.FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., .FALSE., 4294967295)
```

Why are the vectors assigned the integer 2^32 - 1 instead of the logical `.true.`?

Comment: This looks just like a problem with GDB interpretting the value. But I think it is a .TRUE. in fact. Have you noticed any problem in Fortran directly?

Comment: Yes, eventually this lead to a SegFault with error:
_forrtl: severe (408): fort: (2): Subscript #1 of the array IS_LIANA has value 65 which is greater than the upper bound of 17_

Comment: I guess that the segfault is unrelated to this issue. And BTW it is technically not a segfault, but compiler check finding an error. You should read that message and check your bounds.

Comment: Yes sorry I don't know why I had in mind that it was a segfault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Fortran compilers (notably Intel Fortran) use a bit pattern of -1 to represent .TRUE., and some use +1.

Looks like GDB is expecting +1 as .TRUE. and does not know that 4294967295 is also .TRUE., just in a different compiler.

Unsigned integer 4294967295 has the same bit pattern as signed integer -1. All bits are set to 1.

You can change this behaviour by `-standard-semantics` or by `-fpscomp logicals`. Intel Fortran will then use +1 as .TRUE..

Comment: So I am not sure about your answer, on one hand it is true that I compile with intel, on the other I noticed the exact same behavior if I debug with `idb`. Should this also happen with the Intel debugger?

Comment: It might, who knows, Intel has two different modes of operation and idb is prepared only for one of them.

Comment: Generally compiling with -check bounds (or -check all) will help the usual causes of segfaults. There is a similar gfortran switch.

Comment: @Holmz Worth noting that the OP is allready using this switch and his error message comes exactly from that check. However, it is a different issue. Not covered in this answer and not covered in the edited question. He does not have a segfault. See the comments below the question.